# Clip staying on screen while not in timeline anymore

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, tween

I have a particular problem : I have a fla with 2 frames, with a clip of instance name "my_clip" on frame 1 and no clip en frame 2. If i move by code (like a tween) "my_clip", when I go to frame 2, the clip is still on screen, whereas frame 2 is totally empty in my fla.

How flash work at this level ? Does he stop "syncronizing" a clip with the fla once the clip has been moved by code ? How can I check at frame 2 that the scene should be empty ?

(I'm with flash cs 5.5 and player 11)

Comment: post your code or .fla .  You'll need to stop your tween (in frame 2) and removeChild(my_clip)

Answer (score -1):

Actually what FLASH does when we are trying to change the depth or start drag and some more dynamic functionality it freezes the target movieclip in stage. Eventually there is only one stage in FLASH and guess what if the movieclip has been frozen in the stage? It is visible or available always.

So in your case the same has happened. The clip has just frozen to the stage. Needless to say, the second frame is empty always. You don't need to check the second frame. What all you need to do is remove that clip before you navigates to either next frame or scene.

Answer (score -1):

@LondonDrugs_MediaServices : I can't post my code and fla because there is too much code unrelated to the problem.

But as I was trying to make a little fla to reproduce my problem and show it to you, I figure out that the problem was not where I thought it was : I fact it was because each time I start dragging my clip i was doing a setChildIndex on it to put it on top. And it was precisely the setChildIndex wich would cut the "syncronization" between the clip and the fla timeline.

Thanks anyway for your answers, it kind of help me in a way :)